# Mysql SELECT not same encoding between two mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have local environnement development (WAMP) and production environnent on my hoster.

For testing purpose I export my database from hoster and import to my local WAMP environnement.

I have a fonction who take text from my database and generate json file for display.

To display accents I have to use utf8_decode on WAMP environnement but not on my hoster environnement. I checked everthing about encoding and configuration, even if I re-import the same SQL file from my computer on both sides (dev. and prod.) ths problem still exist.

| PARAM | DEV | PROD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PHPMYADMIN VERSION | 5.2.0 | 5.2.1 |
| EXPORT SQL FILE ENCODING | NA | uft-8 |
| EXPORT SQL PARAMETER | (Import from PROD) | data & structure with drop |
| IMPORT SQL FILE ENCODING | uft-8 | NA |
| DATABASE INTERCLASSEMENT | latin1_swedish_ci | latin1_swedish_ci |
| STRUCTURE FIELD COLLATION | latin1_swedish_ci | latin1_swedish_ci |
| MYSQL VERSION | 8.0.31 | ??? |
| PHPVERSION | 8.0.26 | 8.0.28 |
| PHP COINFIG default_charset | UTF-8 / UTF-8 | UTF-8 / UTF-8 |
| WEBSERVER | Apache/2.4.54 | Apache ??? |

So if I don't use utf8_decode in my function:

`"content": "'.(str_replace($badchar, '',str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),'<br/>', $data['avis']))).'"`

dev: "RÃ©gion riche en dÃ©couvertes."
prod: "Région riche en découvertes."

if I use utf8_decode in my function:

"content": "'.utf8_decode(str_replace($badchar, '',str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),'
'

dev: "Région riche en découvertes."
prod: "R�gion riche en d�couvertes."

I don't undersand where the problem come from, apache, mysql, php ?

The function mb_detect_encoding return me UTF-8 both sides.

Full function:

```
function refresh_json_avis($BDD)
{
    $badchar=array(
    // control characters
    chr(0), chr(1), chr(2), chr(3), chr(4), chr(5), chr(6), chr(7), chr(8), chr(9), chr(10),
    chr(11), chr(12), chr(13), chr(14), chr(15), chr(16), chr(17), chr(18), chr(19), chr(20),
    chr(21), chr(22), chr(23), chr(24), chr(25), chr(26), chr(27), chr(28), chr(29), chr(30),
    chr(31),
    // non-printing characters
    chr(127)
    );
    
    $SiteDataClass = new SiteDataClass($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/json/config.json");

    $req =$BDD->prepare('select avis, nom, date, appartement FROM reservations WHERE etat>=6 AND avis!="" ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC');
    $req->execute();
    
    $file='[';
    
    while($data = $req->fetch())
    {        
        $array_date=explode('-',$data['date']);

        $file.='{"title": "'.$SiteDataClass->get_flat_name($data['appartement']).', '.$array_date[2].'/'.$array_date[1].'/'.$array_date[0].'","content": "'.utf8_decode(str_replace($badchar, '',str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),'<br/>', $data['avis']))).'","sign": "'.strtoupper(substr($data['avis'], 0, 1)).'."},';    
    }
    
    $req->closecursor();

    $file = rtrim($file);
    $file = rtrim($file, ",");
    $file.= "]";    
    
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/json/avis.json', $file);

    return('[{"type":"message","content":"'.mb_detect_encoding($file).'","param":"success"}]'); //debug
    return('[{"type":"message","content":"Mis à jour, cela peut mettre plusieurs minutes à apparaitre","param":"success"}]');
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` have been so badly misunderstood over time that they have been [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_utf_8_decode_encode), so I’d recommend avoiding them, even if they appear to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) - Make sure this is the case on both environments.

Comment: For `RÃ©gion`, see "Mojibake".  For `R�gion`, see "black diamond".  Both are discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  Meanwhile, any use of encode/decode functions is probably making things worse.